# check if value exist or lies between particular values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I want to do is input a value and check if the values exist in the array or lies between particular
values of array and get lower range value index

For example I have this array:

```
dataArr = [10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 80, 90, 100];
```

if

```
input = 22;
```

the function should return index of value 20 and 30 from dataArr.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Do you know how to iterate over the values of an array?

Comment: function gt(n){return n>this;} dataArr.findIndex(gt, 22);

Comment: @dandavis findIndex() is not supported in major browsers. It only works in Firefox

Comment: perhaps, but at least it works in my chrome natively and it's easy to poly-fill. you can use filter and look at the .length of the result for a less-efficient but more backwards compat version. It's also around in the popular _ libs

Comment: I know it could be polyfill, but then you shoud give advice on that like providing link like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dataArr = [10, 20, 30, 50, 70, 80, 90, 100];

function _find(array, search) {
  var indexes = [],
      len = array.length,
      i,
      index = array.indexOf(search);

  if (~index) {
    return index;
  }

  if (search < array[0]) {
    return -1;  
  }

  for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if (array[i] >= search) {
      return [i - 1, i];
    }    
  }

  return -1;
}


console.log(_find(dataArr, 22));
```

DEMO: [http://jsbin.com/vakanu/1/](http://jsbin.com/vakanu/1/edit?js,console)

*But array should be sorted*

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using sorted array. Below code will do the trick.

```
 var inputVal = 22
 dataArr = sortThisArray(dataArr); //IF needed
 for (var i=0; i<dataArr.size(); i++)
 {
      if(dataArr[i] > inputVal) //Check if the array value is greater than input value
      {
          if(i < (dataArr.size()-1))
          {
               alert("Range is" + i +"and its last element in array so higher index");
          }
          else //we can find the LOWER BOUND index as i and HIGHER BOUND index as i+1
          {
              alert("Range are" + i +"and"+ i+1);
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: what is dataArr.size() ?